# public class member visible to descendents

Tags: c#, design-patterns, builder-pattern

I have been getting a lot of traction from a builder pattern as a public class member of another class:

```
public class Part
{
    public class Builder
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }

        public Part Build()
        {
            return new Part(Name, Type);
        }
    }

    protected Part(string name, int type)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note protected constructor - I like how I HAVE to use the builder to get a Part. Calls to

```
Part p = new Part.Builder() { Name = "one", Type = 1 }.Build();
```

work great. What I would like to do is use this builder to serve up a special kind of part based on the Type (for example):

```
public class SpecialPart : Part
{
    protected SpecialPart(string name, int type) : base(name, type) { }
}
```

And a slight change to the builder:

```
public Part Build()
{
    if (Type == _some_number_)
        return new SpecialPart(Name, Type);
    return new Part(Name, Type);
}
```

But this doesn't work - Part.Builder can't see SpecialPart's protected constructor. How can I get Builder to work with descendents of Part and get the same must-have-a-builder semantics?

Comment: Is there a reason Builder is a class, and not just a protected method?

Comment: yes, public, of course.  I was thinking about the constructor.

Comment: @Robert: The nice thing about the class is the object-initializer syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat, but the path of least resistance here is going to be making the constructors of your various part types public or internal.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it, except for putting them in their own assembly and use the internal access specifier.